# How to create httpcookie from string?

Tags: android, cookies

I have cookie string from android cookie manager

```
String stringCookie = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
```

returns

```
hl=ru; PHPSESSID=qmvc3c7qq3r07a3dqn7hgk4065
```

Then, I use HttpCookie.parse

```
List<HttpCookie> cookies = HttpCookie.parse(stringCookie);
          for (HttpCookie c : cookies) {
            Log.e("My WebView","cookie "+ c.toString()+" | "+c.getComment() + " | " +c.getCommentURL()
                + " | " +c.getDomain() + " | " +c.getName() + " | " +c.getPath() + " | " +c.getValue());
          }
```

but, phpsessid is always lost, log shows

```
cookie hl=ru | null | null | null | hl | null | ru
```

How to make propper conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I split initial cookie string to separate cookies strings and then pase them iterativly.

```
ArrayList<HttpCookie> cookiesList = new ArrayList<>();
String[] singleCookie = cookiesString.split(";");
for(String c:singleCookie){
    List<HttpCookie> l = HttpCookie.parse(c);
    cookieList.add(l.get(0));
}
```